# has no method of emit in node.js

Tags: node.js, eventemitter

I made a simple example like below, and I got a error saying 'has no method of 'emit'  ', what is the issue ?

```
var events = require('events');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var util = require('util');

var Door = function (options) {
    events.EventEmitter.call(this);
}   

util.inherits(Door, EventEmitter);


Door.prototype = {
    open:function(){
       this.emit('open');
    }
}

var frontDoor = new Door('brown');

frontDoor.on('open', function() {
    console.log('ring ring ring');
  });
frontDoor.open();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing the prototype of `Door` with a new object, which overwrites (/removes) the `EventEmitter` prototype methods as well:

```
Door.prototype = {
    open:function(){
       this.emit('open');
    }
}
```

Instead, just add a single entry to the existing prototype:

```
Door.prototype.open = function() {
  this.emit('open');
};
```

Comment: Hi, @robertklep, it works well. just wonder is there alliterative to keep the  Door.prototype = {   xxx:function(){}  } while can adding the eventemitter.

Comment: @user824624 I don't think there's an easy way, no.